# Spring integration inbound-channel-adapter triggered at post construct?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, enterprise-integration

Suppose I have this class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public String myMethod() {
         //...
    }
}
```

What I want is when my application starts, to send the result that `myMethod()` returns to a certain channel in Spring Integration. What I have tried:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="myPackage.MyClass"/>

<int:inbound-channel-adapter channel="channelINeedToSendTo" ref="myClass" method="myMethod">
    <int:poller cron=""/>  <!-- poller configuration -->
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Now what can I configure in poller is to call `myMethod()` at a certain time, on regularly on a certain scheduling, but I wanted to be run exactly after the application started (something like `@PostConstruct`). Is there a simple way achieving this, without complicated AOP techniques?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an [Event Inbound Channel Adapter](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/applicationevent.html) to capture the `ContextRefreshedEvent` Application Event; then wire that adapter to a `<service-activator/>` that invokes `myMethod()`; the result will be on the `output-channel`.